# Can Twilio handle inbound group MMS

Tags: twilio

I've been searching through the documentation and am having trouble figuring out how/if Twilio handles inbound group MMS.

What I would like to do is have my application receive a webhook if the Twilio number is added to a group chat, be able to view all participants in the chat, and store some type of reference to it so a response can be sent after some processing occurs. I'd like for all members of the group chat to receive the response in the group chat itself (I'm testing with iMessage), rather than individually.

I've successfully been able to do this in a 1 to 1 chat with my Twilio number, but when a group chat is started my application is only able to reply directly to the sender of a given message, and cannot see other members of the chat.

Answer (score -1):

Twilio Conversations does provide support.

[Group texting in Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/group-texting)

Comment: Link goes to 404 page as of 2022-05-17 08:00.

Comment: Limitation to Group MMS - https://www.twilio.com/changelog/limitation-to-group-mms. My understanding is carrier migration over to 10DLC routes introduced compatibility issues with group MMS that must be resolved before it will be opened back up.